# magento 2 get credit card full name based on 'cc_type' code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Inside of my payment class in

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment)
```

object `$payment` has method `$payment->getCcType()` which returns short code 'VI' or 'AE'for example. And I need to get full name of credit card brand, which `$payment` doesn't has (I've looked at realization of InfoInterface - there is nothing about it).
The name should match one of this list AMEX, DISCOVER, DINERSCLUB, VISA, MASTERCARD, JCB, UNIONPAY, VOYAGER, CARTEBLEUE, DANKORT, MAESTRO, VPAY, VISAELECTRON, TOKEN, VISADELTADEBIT, MASTERCARDDEBIT (doesn't matter whether it is lower or uppercase).
How it could be converted using magento framework or payment modules?

Answer (score 4):

After debugging couple of hours i have resolved this issue by following below method.

**template.phtml**

```
<div class="ccType"> 
   <span> Card Type: <span> 
   <?php echo $block->getCardFullName("cardCode") // VI / AE... ?>
</div>
```

**Block.php**

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Customer\Cards;

class Listing extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public $ccConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\CcConfig $ccCongig,
        array $data = []
    ) {  
        $this->ccConfig = $ccCongig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
     }

    public function getCardFullName($CardCode)
    {
        $return = "";
        if($CardCode){
            $cardTypes = $this->ccConfig->getCcAvailableTypes();
            $return = $cardTypes[$CardCode];
        }
        return $return; // Visa / American Express ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to instatiate `Magento\Payment\Model\CcConfig` class, and use `getCcAvailableTypes` method of it.

It'll return this array:

```
Array
(
    [AE] => American Express
    [VI] => Visa
    [MC] => MasterCard
    [DI] => Discover
    [JCB] => JCB
    [SM] => Switch/Maestro
    [DN] => Diners
    [SO] => Solo
    [MI] => Maestro International
    [MD] => Maestro Domestic
    [OT] => Other
)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. But what if some of my credit cards are not in list? VISAELECTRON, TOKEN, VISADELTADEBIT, MASTERCARDDEBIT for example. Do I have some options to use them? And what about names - I guess I need to write some converter method, for example to get 'AMEX' from '[AE] => American Express', right? Is there some other way?